# Mongoose findOne() not returning entire document

Tags: mongoose, discord.js

So I have this Schema

```js
const playerCharacter = new Schema({
  userID: String,
  guildID: String,
  username: String,
  characterName: String,
  characterImgUrl: String,
  hp: [Number, Number],
  humanity: [Number, Number],
  role: String,
  abilities: [{ name: String, rank: Number }],
  criticalInjuries: [String],
  addictions: [String],
  eb: Number,
  ip: Number,
  stats: {
    ...
  },
  skills: {
    ...
  },
  armor: {
   ...
  },
  weapons: [
    {
      ref: String,
      name: String,
      ammo: Number,
      magSize: String,
      ammoLoaded: String,
      rangeDV: [Number],
      dmg: String,
      standardMag: Number,
      extendedMg: Number,
      drumMag: Number,
      rof: Number,
      hands: Number,
      isAutofire: Boolean,
      afMultiplier: Number,
      suppressiveFire: Boolean,
      skillRef: String,
      skillName: String,
      ammoType: String,
      cost: Number,
    },
  ],
  ammo: [{ ref: String, name: String, type: String, amount: Number }],
  cyberwear: [{ ref: String, name: String, desc: String }],
  inventory: [{ ref: String, name: String, amount: Number }],
});
```

And I use this query:

```js
 const pc = await Character.findOne({
      userID: `${interaction.member.id}`,
    });
```

The `console.log(pc)` returns the document correctly until here...

```
}
  ],
  cyberwear: [
    { ref: 'neural_link', name: 'Neural Link', desc: ' ' },
    { ref: 'cyber_deck', name: 'Cyberdeck', desc: ' ' }
  ],
  inventory: [],
  __v: 1
}
```

If I delete the nested object in the Schema to get `ammo: [{}]` or use `.lean()` the document returns correctly. I would use `.lean()` to get the document correctly, or delete the object schema if I didn't need to change the values and `.save()`.

Considering that I use very similar definitions for "cyberwear", it seems strange the the "ammo" definition is behaving this way.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: It didn't show the "ammo" array of objects because one of the key-value pairs used the name "type". I feel like a dumb.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).